# Templated class assignment in C++

Tags: c++, templates

This might be a very basic question, but I searched and couldn't find anything.

I have some code that looks like this:

```
if(var == 1) {
  MyClass<A> x();
  x.doThing1();
  x.doThing2();
  x.doThing3();
  ...
  x.doThing10();
} else if(var == 2) {
  MyClass<B> x();
  x.doThing1();
  x.doThing2();
  x.doThing3();
  ...
  x.doThing10();
} else {
  MyClass<C> x();
  x.doThing1();
  x.doThing2();
  x.doThing3();
  ...
  x.doThing10();
}
```

What I'd like to do instead is to cut down the number of lines, e.g.:

```
// obviously non-working code
MyClass<auto> x;
if(var == 1) {
  x<A>();
} else if(var == 2) {
  x<B>();
} else {
  x<C>();
}
x.doThing1();
x.doThing2();
x.doThing3();
...
x.doThing10();
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you can do.

In the general case, if you don't mind dynamic memory allocation, you can take define the interface in a virtual base class, implement the interface in MyClass, using whatever you need from the template parameter. Something along these lines:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    virtual void doThing1() const = 0;
    virtual void doThing2() const = 0;
    virtual void doThing3() const = 0;
};

template <class T>
class MyClass: public Base
{
public:
    void doThing1() const {std::cout << T::foo << ".doThing1()" << std::endl;}
    void doThing2() const {std::cout << T::foo << ".doThing2()" << std::endl;}
    void doThing3() const {std::cout << T::foo << ".doThing3()" << std::endl;}
};
struct A {static const char foo = 'A';};
struct B {static const char foo = 'B';};
struct C {static const char foo = 'C';};

std::unique_ptr<Base> makeMyClassInstance(const int var)
{
    switch (var)
    {
        case 1: return std::make_unique<MyClass<A> >();
        case 2: return std::make_unique<MyClass<B> >();
        case 3: return std::make_unique<MyClass<C> >();
        default: throw std::runtime_error("unsupported");
    }
}
int main()
{
    int var = 1;
    const auto x = makeMyClassInstance(var);
    x->doThing1();
    x->doThing2();
    x->doThing3();
}
```

If var is not a variable but can be known at compile time, you can have a more radical design. I am skipping the MyClass in this case, but you will get the idea:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

struct A{void foo() {std::cout << "A" << std::endl;}};
struct B{void foo() {std::cout << "B" << std::endl;}};
struct C{void foo() {std::cout << "C" << std::endl;}};

template <int I>
struct SelectType
{
    typedef typename std::remove_reference<decltype(std::get<I-1> (std::make_tuple(A(), B(), C())))>::type type;
};

template <int I, class T = typename SelectType<I>::type>
T makeMyClassInstance() {return T();}

int main()
{
    auto x1 = makeMyClassInstance<2>();
    x1.foo(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I like your first solution the best.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can just refactor it into something like:

```
template <class T>
void doThings()
{
  MyClass<T> t;
  t.doThing1();
  // ...
  t.doThing10();
}

// dispatch
switch (var)
{
case 1: doThings<A>(); break;
case 2: doThings<B>(); break;
// ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping there was a solution that keeps everything in place.  I feel like having a dispatch function decreases readability, since you'd have to jump around.

Comment: How does adding a dispatch function decrease readability when you intend to dispatch? Are you trying to hide what you are doing for some reason? And how does hiding what you are doing improve readability?
And what do you mean by "jump around?" How can you remove duplicate code, but leave things in place? Those seem like two conflicting goals. You want to replace duplicated blocks of code with a function, yet you don't want to define that function elsewhere? How is that possible to achieve?